# Replace space with underscore in Notepad++ in xml file

Tags: xml, regex, notepad++

I have an xml manifest that I need to replace the spaces with underscores in. It looks like this:

```
<file href="MOSQ_19D_NEW/references/FM 21-75.pdf" />
<file href="MOSQ_19D_NEW/references/FM 3-01.80.pdf" />
<file href="MOSQ_19D_NEW/references/FM 3-09.30 TTPs for Observed Fire and Fire Support at BN Task Force and Below.pdf" />
```

So I need to find where there is a space and replace with an underscore between the xml brackets and the qoutes. I have to do this manually very often at my job.

I have tried many things but cannot figure this out.

Comment: Do you mean to replace the spaces between the quotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is this:

```
(?<=".*) (?=.*")
```

Unfortunately, notepad++ doesn't support zero width assertions, therefore you will have to either :

- Use a third party tool/program/language which supports this
- Use this : `(href="\S*)\s(.*?")` replace with `\1_\2` repeatedly

Until no more replacements are possible.

Comment: (href="\S*)\s(.*?") replace with $1_$2 just replaced the whole href="blah blah.pdf" part with $1_$2. What tool would you use instead?

Comment: @lazfish Please check updated answer. I would personally use perl. To do this. You don't even need a script, a one liner can execute the regex I wrote.

Comment: @lazfish You are definitely **wrong** here. I just tested **your** example with notepad++ version 5.9.4 and it worked just fine.

Comment: You are right. I don't know why it didn't work before. Thanks. I'll tuck this into my tool box.

Comment: @lazfish Happens to the best of us :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a crappy, but maybe helpful solution:

Find what: `(".*) (.*")`

Replace with: `\1_\2`

It's crappy, because you'll have to "Replace all" as many times as the maximum number of a spaces there can be in a single line. So if you have 1000 lines, and but there's at most 5 spaces in a single line, you'll have to "Replace all" for 5 times.

Comment: \1_\2 replaced everything in "MOSQ_19D_NEW/references/FM 21-75.pdf"

Comment: Also I noticed this selects the whole quotation part. Should it select just the space.

Comment: Are you using the newest version of np++? For me it works fine. Yes, id does select the whole part, and replaces the whole part, but partially with itself. See those \1 and \2? Those are references for the stuff inside the (). What those parts will match will be found in the replacing string.

Comment: Yeah your right. I don't know why it wasn't working. It might have been an option I had set in the alternative regex (Ctrl+R). Thanks!