# Replace whitespaces between specific strings

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'm trying to replace whitespaces with underscores in certain parts of my html-document with Notepad++.

I can identify the area to search for the whitespaces in the following way:

-Begins with: src="video/

-Ends with: mp4

For example I might have a line like this:

```
<video class="play" src="video/my file name with empty spaces.mp4">
```

and I would like to change it to be like this:

```
<video class="play" src="video/my_file_name_with_empty_spaces.mp4">
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8186488/replace-space-with-underscore-in-notepad-in-xml-file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Tested in N++**

Search: `(?:src="video|(?<!^)\G)(?:(?!mp4).)*?\K\s+`

Replace: `_`

On [the demo](http://regex101.com/r/gY7rO4/37), see the substitutions at the bottom.

**Explanation**

- `(?:src="video|(?<!^)\G)` matches the delimiter `src="video`, or `\G` the position following the previous match as long as it is not at the beginning of the string `(?<!^)` where `\G` can also match
- `(?:(?!mp4).)` matches one character that is not followed by `mp4`
- `*?` lazily matches such characters, up to...
- `\s` a space character (our match which we replace with `_`)
- before the space,  the `\K` tells the engine to drop what was matched so far from the final match it returns

[image: NPP]

Comment: FYI: Added demo and screenshot, let me know if you have questions. :)

Comment: Wow that was insanely more complicated than what I expected, but it works! :)

Comment: Good use of `G` and `K` can you explain a bit more about it.

Comment: @Braj Added explanation.

Comment: @Braj Thanks, glad you like it. :)